# Mysql : Match Against query

Tags: mysql

Due to BigData I want to use Match against in place of like. My Column is FULL INDEXED.
What is the alternate of this Query, in Match against.

MySQL Query is:

```
 select count(*) from keywords where sb_keyword like 'a%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this exactly what the query is?

```
select count(*) from keywords where sb_keyword like 'a%'
```

That should benefit from  `INDEX(sb_keyword)`.  A `FULLTEXT` index is not practical for this query, either as it stands or using `WHERE MATCH(sb_keyword) AGAINST(+a* IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.

It will take time to walk through all the values starting with a to count them.  The index I suggested helps because and index is (usually) smaller then the entire dataset due to having fewer 'columns'.

Comment: WHERE MATCH(sb_keyword) AGAINST(+a* IN BOOLEAN MODE) shows an error

Comment: @SyedDaniyalAsif - quotes are missing.  Also, it won't be very efficient to look for just the first letter.